# Tricky string separation on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to separate strings within Python.

Data

```
 Type                 Id        
 aa - generation      aa - generation01 
 aa_led - generation  aa_led - generation01
 ss - generation      ss- generation01
```

Desired

```
Type    Id
aa      aa01
aa_led  aa_led01
ss      ss01
```

Doing

I am trying to incorporate this code into my script, however, I keep getting a NoneType error

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x : x.replace('- generation', '').replace(' ',''))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `\s*` for zero or more spaces before `- generation`:

```
df = df.replace('\s*- generation', '', regex=True)
print (df)
     Type        Id
0      aa      aa01
1  aa_led  aa_led01
2      ss      ss01
```

Error means there are some `None` values, so for working your solution is possible use `if-else` statement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ "aa - generation", "aa - generation01"],
                   ["aa_led - generation", "aa_led - generation01"],
                   ["ss - generation", None ]], 
                  columns=['Type', 'Id'])
print(df)
                  Type                     Id
0      aa - generation      aa - generation01
1  aa_led - generation  aa_led - generation01
2      ss - generation                   None

func = lambda x : x.replace('- generation', '').replace(' ','') if pd.notna(x) else None
df = df.applymap(func)
print (df)
     Type        Id
0      aa      aa01
1  aa_led  aa_led01
2      ss      None
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution, it works:

code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[ "aa - generation", "aa - generation01"],
                   ["aa_led - generation", "aa_led - generation01"],
                   ["ss - generation", "ss- generation01"  ]], columns=['Type', 'Id'])
print(df)
df = df.applymap(lambda x : x.replace('- generation', '').replace(' ',''))
print(df)
```

result:

```sh
                  Type                     Id
0      aa - generation      aa - generation01
1  aa_led - generation  aa_led - generation01
2      ss - generation       ss- generation01
     Type        Id
0      aa      aa01
1  aa_led  aa_led01
2      ss      ss01
```